# How to hide a video when it's ended?

Tags: jquery, html5-video

How do you hide a video when it's ended? I tried `$("video#video-to-play").css('display','none');` when it ended and it didn't hide the video when it ended.

```
$('video#video-to-play').on('ended',function(){
   $(".shown .media-contain").transition({ opacity: 0 });
   $("#next-item,#next-item2,#next-item3").click();
   $("video#video-to-play").css('display','none');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
$('video#video-to-play').on('ended',function(){
   $(".shown .media-contain").transition({ opacity: 0 });
   $("video#video-to-play").css({'visibility':'hidden'});
   $("#next-item,#next-item2,#next-item3").click();
});
```